# Adobe AIR - How do I create a tree list to organize media

Tags: xml, database, apache-flex, air, adobe

I want to create an AIR app to organize media compilations.

```
i.e. Compilation_1
           -Song1
           -Song2
           -Song3
     Compilation_2
           -Song1
           -Song2
           -Song3
           -Song4
```

On the UI the user must be able to enter a title for the compilation, then add add track titles. The only other requirement I have is that the list must be searchable.

I haven't done anything involving tree lists, databases or xml before. Can someone give me a roadmap and tell me what I should be researching to complete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should start with a [`Tree`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_8.html) control.  Since there's no Spark version yet, you should also look at how to [mix MX and Spark components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-1c32bcb9124deadc3e9-8000.html#WS03d33b8076db57b9-3edf2834124deb0ca54-7ffe).

There's also an [alternative implementation](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Spark_Tree-17788.html) to consider using.  If neither gets you all the way there, then looking at their source should help you along.

Searchability would be a feature of the data structure.  If you use ended up using XML, you could transate the user query into E4X.